# Rewrite old subfolder url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

I have moved my site subfolder to root. "http:// anumuhammad .net/home" to "http:// anumuhammad .net/"

This site have lot of backlink url and I need all old url redirected to new url:

http:// anumuhammad . net/ home /article/212-2015-07-04-14-14-20
to
http:// anumuhammad . net/ article/212-2015-07-04-14-14-20

http:// anumuhammad . net/home/article/ to http:// anumuhammad . net/article/
http://anumuhammad.net/home/books/ to http://anumuhammad.net/books/

"home" should be remove when visitor came from old backlink. I have searched lot but could not found a solution that help me.

This is addon website in apache server.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Julash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
 RedirectMatch ^/home/(.*)$ http://anumuhammad.net/$1
```

Comment: it just needed a little tweak, which is to add 'www'. Otherwise people who came from "www.anumuhammad.net/...." source dont get redirected to proper url. So the rewirterule should be "RedirectMatch ^/home/(.*)$ http://www.anumuhammad.net/$1" with "www".